# OOP Practice/Structure for AS3 Game

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm a bit of a newb to as3 game development but I want to create a somewhat flexible base for a Connect Four game. I'd like to be able to skin the game board and game pieces. Here's what I'm thinking so far. If anyone has suggestions I'd really appreciate it:

GameController extends EventDispatcher
- Contains all game grid manipulation methods.
- Includes 2D array to keep track of GamePiece locations
- Dispatches events after validation when methods are invoked

GameClass extends Sprite:
- Holds visual elements of the board
- MouseEvent Listeners attached to visual elements, which invoke controller methods
- (Custom) ControllerEvent Listeners to update visual look when GameController dispatches

GamePiece Class extend Sprite:
- Holds piece's column/row location
- Holds currentPlayer index
- Loads PNG URL as skin

That's  the rough outline. Any red flags or other suggestions are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like the GridController is going to suffer from mixed responsibilities; in MVC architectures the Controller's responsibility is to shuffle data back and forth from the Model to the View.  Personally I would consider having a GridModel which would hold the underlying multidimensional Array which represents the grid and methods for adding pieces, eg:

```
public class GridModel extends EventDispatcher {
    private var _grid :  Array;

    public function GridModel(rows : uint, cols : uint) : void {
        // Create the data structure which represents the Grid.
        _grid = initialiseGrid(rows, cols);
    }

    public function addPiece(player : uint, col : uint) : void {
        if (isValidMove(col)) {
            // Update the datastructure, determine which row the piece ended
            // up residing in.
            const row : uint = // method omitted

            // Notify the rest of the system that a move has been made.
            dispatchEvent(new GridUpdateEvent(GridUpdateEvent.MOVE, player, col, row, _grid.concat());
        }
        else {
            // Illegal Move, datastructure stays the same, notify the rest
            // of the system.
            dispatchEvent(new IllegalMoveEvent(IllegalMoveEvent.COLUMN_FULL, player, col, _grid.concat()));
        }
    }
}
```

The primary role of your Controller would now be to listen to the events dispatched by the model and then update the View (DisplayList) accordingly.  Like-wise, your View should dispatch Events based on user interaction (eg: Player one has indicated that they wish to drop a piece  into the 2nd column); the Controller can then call the relevant method on the Model.

The following snippet should give you some indication as to what the responsibilties of the Controller are; don't forget that you can (and should!) break your responsibilities down by making use of multiple Models, Views and, if required Controllers.

```
public class GameController {
    private var _gridModel : GridModel;
    private var _stateModel : GameStateModel;
    private var _gridView : GridView;

    public function GameController(gridModel : GridModel, gameStateModel : GameStateModel, gridView : GridView) {
        _gridModel = gridModel;
        _gameStateModel : gameStateModel;
        _gridView = gridView;

        addEventListeners();
    }

    private function addEventListeners() : void {
        _gridModel.addEventListener(GridUpdateEvent.MOVE, onGridUpdateMoveEvent);
        _gridView.addEventListener(ColumnSelectionEvent.SELECTED, onColumnSelectedEvent);
    }

    private function onColumnSelectedEvent(event : ColumnSelectionEvent) : void {
         // Query the GameStateModel to find out whos turn it currently is.
         const activePlayer : uint = _gameStateModel.activePlayer;

         // Ask the GridModel to update.
        _gridModel.addPiece(activePlayer, event.column);
    }

    private function onGridUpdateMoveEvent(event : GridUpdateEvent) : void {
        // Update the view.
        _gridView.insertPiece(event.player, event.row, event.col);

        // Update the GameState to indicate it's the next player turns.
        _gameSate.completeTurn();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic thanks I completely follow the logic. I thought of making separate classes for GridModel and the GameState but I fell into the old trap of being lazy and asking 'does it really need its own class?' I certainly see the power of decoupling that relationship even on this level.

Comment: One reason to separate the GameStateModel from the GridModel woudl be to vary the number of players; the GridModel doesn't care how many people are playing the game, that's the responsibility of the GameStateModel.  By making use of polymorphism you could easily swap between a TwoPlayerGameStateModel and a ThreePlayerGameStateModel.